How to monitor new pairs and liquidity pools in mempool pending transactions?
I have a task to monitor newly created pairs PairCreated() and adding new liquidity pools Mint(). That is some kind of sniper bots like banana or maestro that are watching mempool and send buy transactions just in the same block as liquidity pool was created. How to do that? With python language and websockets I can monitor pending transactions and get their hash. But what to do next, how to decode data?
For example, this transactions https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe0a465d1e4a622ca43db886b589122c6f44390b6a1a1715aab0948ac246619c9 is about to create new pair on Uniswap V2 and add pool by minting. If I read input data of transaction, there will be only 0xc9567bf9. This is information will not tell me what will happen.
I have read about EVM Tracing, is it what I am looking for? How to use it?
This is starter code:
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

async def get_event():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8546/') as ws:
        await ws.send('{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}')
        subscription_response = await ws.recv()

        while True:
            message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=15)
            tx_hash = json.loads(message)['params']['result']

            # I got transaction hash
            # now I can get more data web3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)
            # but what to do next?


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(get_event())


'id': 1,
'method': 'debug_traceCall',
'jsonrpc': '2.0',
'params': [
    tx,
    'pending',
    {'tracer': 'callTracer', "tracerConfig": {"withLog": true}}
]

